# PHP not executing on Xcode simulator using Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am creating a non-native iOS application in an HTML5/Javascript/CSS3 implementation. I have an external PHP file on my localhost and am trying to communicate with it using jQuery and AJAX.

Everything works fine if I make the request to the PHP file in my browser and I get the desired response, so there is no problem code-wise.

However when running it in Xcode's simulator, the PHP doesn't execute and I just receive the whole PHP script as the response. I don't know why it isn't executing and I've been stuck on the problem for ages, Please can anyone help?

I have already tried putting header("access-control-allow-origin: *"); at the top of the php page but I am still getting no result.

Would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Is it possible that the emulator is loading the PHP script from disk directly, rather than requesting it from the web server?

Comment: sounds like a possibility! Could I get around that by creating a virtual host and giving the jquery the url rather than just a file path of the php?

Comment: @Cylus27 yes, you should be able to get around it like that. You could also try using your local IP (e.g. 192.168.1.3/phpfile.php) for testing purposes. Getting the whole PHP script as a response means it isn't being parsed.

Comment: If you're giving jQuery the file path it's certainly loading the script directly. A virtual host seems overkill - can't you just use `localhost`?

Comment: localhost works!! Thanks